# Reverse of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Define a function reverse() that computes the reversal of a string. For example, reverse("jag testar")should return the string "ratset gaj".As I am getting errors and I am new to javascript .I got the code .but it is not executing

```
//my code 
function (string)
{
    var length = string.length;
    var reversed = [];
    var joined = ("");
    for (var i = length; i > 0; i--){
        reversed.push(string.charAt(i-1));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (length) ; i++){
        joined += (reversed[i]);

    }

    return joined ;
```

Comment: `function reverse(s){return s.length?reverse(s.slice(1))+s[0]:''}`

Comment: `string.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: In the above code  function name is missing as Reverse reverse(string).If I use this ,It is sending  unused variable like that

Comment: seems to be working- http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fxy0rwu7/1/

Comment: @elclanrs It is not executing also

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/w6LkvL99/), but ideally you'd use what nnnnnn posted.

Comment: The function has no name, and the closing `}` is missing. Could you post the real function?

Comment: @elclanrs   where i can use that string.split("").reverse().join("").please help me as I am new to js

Comment: @Barmar it is similar type of code .syntax error i can verify .as i am new to js . i am unable to understand string.split("").reverse().join("") where to use in my code .please help me

Comment: @lakshmiadityapavan check the edit in my answer, I hope this clarifies your doubts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the OP:

```
function (string)
```

In a function declaration, a name is mandatory, so:

```
function reverse(string)

{
    var length = string.length;
```

There is no need for *length*, just initialise *i* in the for loop to *string.length*.

```
    var reversed = [];
    var joined = ("");
```

There is no need for the grouping operator:

```
    var joined = "";
```

But there's no need for *joined* at all.

```
    for (var i = length; i > 0; i--){
        reversed.push(string.charAt(i-1));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (length) ; i++){
        joined += (reversed[i]);
    }
```

why put the characters into an array, then iterate over the array to put them back into a string? Immediately after the first loop you could do:

```
  return reversed.join('');

    return joined ;
```

You omitted the closing bracket:

```
}
```

As noted in comments, you can use *split*, *reverse* and *join*, or a recursive function. You could also use *split* and *forEach*,  but probably faster to use a plain loop as you've done:

```
function reverse(s) {
  var result = '',
      i = s.length;

  while (i) {
    result += s[--i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Though `+=` can be slow in some older browsers. Maybe test performance - oh look, it's [been done](http://jsperf.com/string-reverse-compare)… and a plain loop is fastest by a long way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1**: your `function` is not well declared:

```
function (string)
```

The correct way to declare functions in `javascript` is:

```
function functionName(varName)
```

**Point 2** (i guess typo): your function must end with `}` if not will throw error.

So in your concrete case, if you replace your function for this:

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

And call it in this way:

```
var yourString = "ABCDE";
var reversedString = reverse(yourString);  

// reversedString = "EDCBA"
```

To understand how it works:

- It splits the string into single char array with `split("")`, so `"ABCDE".split("") = ["A","B","C","D","E"]`
- The `arrays:reverse()` function of invert the order, so `["A","B","C","D","E"].reverse() = ["E","D","C","B","A"]`.
- `join("")` reconstructs the string again, so `["E","D","C","B","A"].join("") = "EDCBA"`

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to reverse the order of the elements in the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    fruits.reverse();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: But...the question is about a string, not an array.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It appears that you have copied this from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_reverse) without attribution. When using content from other sources, please provide attribution (by providing a link to it) and note that any relevant content is from that source. For more information, please read the [referencing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Thanks!

Comment: thanks to giving attention to me